Adding graphics to a ReasonML project
I've looked at this question -- How do I add an OCaml library reference to a Reason code file? -- which shows how to add an OCaml library to a ReasonML project. But it doesn't seem to be working for me. Part of the problem is that I don't really know what esy and dune are doing, and stepping through the examples that tell me what to type is all very well...except I don't know why I'm typing it.
I've got a dune file:
(executable
  (public_name graphics_example.exe)
  (name graphics_example)
  (libraries graphics))

I've got a package.json file copied from the hello-reason example:
{
  "name": "hello-reason",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Example Reason Esy Project",
  "license": "MIT",
  "esy": {
    "build": "dune build -p #{self.name}",
    "buildDev": "dune build --promote-install-files --root . --only-package #{self.name}",
    "NOTE": "Optional release Section. Customizes result of `esy release`",
    "release": { "rewritePrefix": true, "bin": [ "Hello" ] },
    "buildEnv": { "ODOC_SYNTAX": "re" }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "esy x Hello",
    "format": "esy dune build @fmt --auto-promote",
    "doc": "esy dune build @doc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@opam/dune": "*",
    "@opam/reason": "*",
    "ocaml": "5.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@opam/ocaml-lsp-server": "*",
    "@opam/merlin": "*",
    "@opam/odoc": "*"
  }
}

And I have a ReasonML file, graphics_example.re:
open Graphics;

open_graph("");
set_window_title("SPIKE");

ignore(wait_next_event([Button_down]));

And if I type
dune exec ./graphics_example.exe  

My program actually runs and shows a graphics window. (I installed XQuartz on my Mac M1 to make this happen, following suggestions during earlier experiments.) But if I run esy, I get this:
info esy 0.8.0 (using package.json)
File "dune", line 4, characters 12-20:
4 |  (libraries graphics))
                ^^^^^^^^
Error: Library "graphics" not found.
-> required by
   /Users/jhughes/Documents/Projects/ReasonML/hello-reason-master/_esy/default/store/b/hello_reason-e15a11c9/default/graphics_example.exe
-> required by alias all
-> required by alias default
error: command failed: 'dune' 'build' '--promote-install-files' '--root' '.' '--only-package' 'hello-reason' (exited with 1)
esy-build-package: exiting with errors above...
error: build failed with exit code: 1
  
esy: exiting due to errors above

So I don't understand what I might have done to make a graphics program work even though I can't find the graphics library, and I don't understand why I cannot find the graphics library in the first place, since it's a standard library in OCaml.
I do know that if I remove "graphics" as a library from the dune file, then dune exec ./graphics_example.exe no longer works, so it appears that dune is somehow finding the library that esy cannot find, or ... I don't know. I'd appreciate any clarity at all.

The graphics library is no longer installed (since OCaml 4.09) alongside the OCaml compiler, you need to declare it as an opam dependency in your package.json file.
